# Subscribe S3 events to SQS queue without exposing SQS to the world?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-sqs, amazon-iam

I am struggling with what I would think would be a simple task.

I want to configure my SQS queue to allow S3 buckets in my account to send messages, but disallow outsiders to send messages. (Outsiders means any principal that is not a member of my AWS account)

The only SQS permission configuration that I can get to work is `Effect=Allow, Principals=*, Actions=SQS:SendMessage, Conditions=None`

Any other permission causes me to see this error when I create the [S3 event -> SQS]: `Unable to validate the following destination configurations. Permissions on the destination queue do not allow S3 to publish notifications from this bucket.`

`Principals=*` concerns me. **From the documentation I can find, this means that the SQS queue is accessible from anyone in the world. Is this true? This is obviously very bad.**

How can I allow my S3 buckets to SendMessage to my SQS queue, and not anonymous users to push messages?

It is acceptable to me to allow any resource in my AWS account to SendMessage to SQS. I just need to block access to anonymous AWS users. This is a very basic requirement and I'm very surprised that I can't find a simple way to do this.

Comment: Does setting the principal as the arn of the bucket produce this error also?

Comment: @hephalump How can I add the arn of the bucket as the principal? A S3 bucket arn is not valid entry for the `Principal` property. The tooltip on `Principal` reads: `The AWS account number(s) of the person(s) allowed or denied permissions` -- now, there may be a way to specify the bucket as the principal in the policy document config, but I don't think it will work. I don't think an S3 bucket is a principal, conceptually. (I may be wrong ...)

Comment: It looks a lot like an IAM policy... When you put your 12 digit account number it produces the error also?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find the secure configuration right in the document

```
   "Condition": {
      "ArnLike": { "aws:SourceArn": "arn:aws:s3:*:*:bucket-name" }
   }
```

Note that for both the Amazon SNS and Amazon SQS IAM policies, you can specify the StringLike condition in the policy, instead of the ArnLike condition.

```
"Condition": {         
  "StringLike": { "aws:SourceArn": "arn:aws:s3:*:*:bucket-name" }
  }
```

Full example pulled from [the doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/enable-event-notifications.html#enable-event-notifications-how-to)

```
{
   "Sid": "example-statement-ID",
   "Effect": "Allow",
   "Principal": {
     "AWS": "*"  
   },
   "Action": [
    "SQS:SendMessage"
   ],
   "Resource": "SQS-ARN",
   "Condition": {
      "ArnLike": { "aws:SourceArn": "arn:aws:s3:*:*:bucket-name" }
   }
  }
```

Comment: For other seekers, you can set this policy to the queue, via CLI using `aws sqs set-queue-attributes --queue-url <url> --attributes Policy="JSON stringified policy document"`